# Best way to read a file and output it nicely

Tags: python, bash

This is not duplicated, I'm really trying to do this but I can't.

I have this log file and I want to archive all the information into database.

```
interface: tun0 (10.8.0.0/255.255.255.0)
filter: ( port 53 ) and (ip || ip6)
#
U 2020/03/04 16:28:01.138292 10.8.0.4:52014 -> 8.8.8.8:53 #1
.|...........www.google.com.....
#
U 2020/03/04 16:28:03.011371 10.8.0.4:57054 -> 8.8.8.8:53 #3
cm...........crm.teste.com.....
#
U 2020/03/04 16:28:03.033610 8.8.8.8:53 -> 10.8.0.4:57054 #4
cm...........crm.teste.com................/.rosa.ns
cloudflare...dns.5y3MD..'....`..:.....
#
U 2020/03/04 16:28:05.166480 10.8.0.4:57284 -> 8.8.8.8:53 #5
.{...........crm.teste.tk.....
#
U 2020/03/04 16:28:05.183755 8.8.8.8:53 -> 10.8.0.4:57284 #6
.{...........crm.teste.tk................0.a.ns...joost.zuurbier.dot..^_.H..*0......:.....
#
U 2020/03/04 16:28:11.153329 10.8.0.4:58086 -> 8.8.8.8:53 #7
.............cbdfhkrlmnsxtvwz.neverssl.com.....
#
U 2020/03/04 16:28:11.180992 8.8.8.8:53 -> 10.8.0.4:58086 #8
.............cbdfhkrlmnsxtvwz.neverssl.com..............;...............;...............;...............;.....=
#
U 2020/03/04 16:28:15.851360 10.8.0.4:60006 -> 8.8.8.8:53 #9
.............plus.l.google.com.....
#
U 2020/03/04 16:28:15.859538 8.8.8.8:53 -> 10.8.0.4:60006 #10
.............plus.l.google.com..............+...:.n
#
U 2020/03/04 16:28:17.316359 10.8.0.4:59708 -> 8.8.8.8:53 #11
.X...........endpoint.prod.eu-west-1.forester.a2z.com.....
#
U 2020/03/04 16:28:17.322547 8.8.8.8:53 -> 10.8.0.4:59708 #12
.X...........endpoint.prod.eu-west-1.forester.a2z.com.................6.T4............4./p............4.5}............cP.%............6.V)............4...............6L.G............6Le.
#
U 2020/03/04 16:28:17.335399 10.8.0.4:53174 -> 8.8.8.8:53 #13
&-...........aafreudservice.prod.us-east-1.freud.titan.assistant.a2z.com.....
#
U 2020/03/04 16:28:17.341750 8.8.8.8:53 -> 10.8.0.4:53174 #14
&-...........aafreudservice.prod.us-east-1.freud.titan.assistant.a2z.com..............,.B'aafreudservice-elb-v7u7pd55xwdw-7511167.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.D.Y.......,..4..Z.Y.......,....8Z
#
U 2020/03/04 16:28:17.363490 10.8.0.4:56468 -> 8.8.8.8:53 #15
nr...........match.amazonbrowserapp.de.....
#
U 2020/03/04 16:28:17.369720 8.8.8.8:53 -> 10.8.0.4:56468 #16
nr...........match.amazonbrowserapp.de..............)..6. 

#
U 2020/03/04 16:28:18.024460 10.8.0.4:64589 -> 8.8.8.8:53 #17
.............identity.browserapps.amazon.de.....
#
U 2020/03/04 16:28:18.030664 8.8.8.8:53 -> 10.8.0.4:64589 #18
.............identity.browserapps.amazon.de................#.identity.browserapps.amazon.co.uk..<.......7..6.$.
#
U 2020/03/04 16:28:18.473433 10.8.0.4:49952 -> 8.8.8.8:53 #19
.............titan.service.amazonbrowserapp.co.uk.....
#
U 2020/03/04 16:28:18.479444 8.8.8.8:53 -> 10.8.0.4:49952 #20
.............titan.service.amazonbrowserapp.co.uk..............%..4^.o
exit
20 received, 20 matched
```

I want to read this lines to work on it and send to db.

I want something like

```
['2020/03/04', '16:28:01.138292', '10.8.0.4:52014', 'www.google.com']
```

**OR**

```
['2020/03/04', '16:28:05.166580', '10.8.0.4:57284', '.{...........crm.teste.tk.....']
```

I know the referes (websites) have different line starts it can be the full line its the same for me. I just want to work with this information the best I can.

I want to use python or bash script.

I have the following script atm:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json
import MySQLdb
import os
import datetime
from shutil import copyfile
import time

# EXPORT EXPORT # 

data = open('/etc/openvpn/logs/teste.txt', 'r')

data = data.read().split('\n')

all_results = []

result = []

for row in data:
    if row.startswith('U '):
        if result:
            result = []
        row = row.replace('U', '').split(' ')
        result.append(row)

    elif row.startswith('.|'):
        row = row.replace('.|', '').replace('..', '')
        result.append(row)
        if result:
            all_results.append(result)
            result = []


data = json.dumps(all_results)
print data
```

The output of this script

```
[[["", "2020/03/04", "16:28:01.138292", "10.8.0.4:52014", "->", "8.8.8.8:53", "#1"], ".www.google.com."], [["", "2020/03/04", "16:28:01.146332", "8.8.8.8:53", "->", "10.8.0.4:52014", "#2"], ".www.google.com+"]]
```

I want to work better with this and also run a FOR to read each position [x][0] .....

Thanks

**EDIT:**

All worked with that file. I run NGREP for some more minutes and I visited random websites and this is the new output:

**https://github.com/henriquemota99/Bugs/blob/master/output.rtf**
(Forget the \ after all the lines, github added that and I don't know why)

Then I run this amazing python script with help of the guys who helped me.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb
import json
# EXPORT EXPORT # 

data = open('/etc/openvpn/logs/teste.txt', 'r')

data = data.read().split('\n')

all_results = []

result = []

for row in data:
    if row.startswith('U '):
        if result:
            result = []
        row = row.replace('U', '').split(' ')
    result.extend(row[1:4])

    elif row.startswith('.'):
        row = row.replace('.|', '').replace('..', '')
        result.append(row.strip('.'))
        if result:
            all_results.append(result)
            result = []

data = json.dumps(all_results)

print data
print all_results[0][0]
print all_results[0][1][ : all_results[0][1].rfind('.') ]
print all_results[0][2]
print all_results[0][3]


db = MySQLdb.connect(user="USER",passwd="PASSWORD",host="IP",db="DB")
cursor = db.cursor()

i = 0


for obj in all_results:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO logsRequests (date, hour, userIp, referer) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (all_results[i][0], all_results[i][1][ : all_results[i][1].rfind('.') ], all_results[i][2], all_results[i][3]))
        i+=1

db.commit()
db.close()
```

If I run script with the first output I got all works fine, with this one seems not working.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests.py", line 46, in <module>
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO logsRequests (date, hour, userIp, referer) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (all_results[i][0], all_results[i][1][ : all_results[i][1].rfind('.') ], all_results[i][2], all_results[i][3]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why? I see sometimes there is empty lines on file and the 3rd position is blank and thats why it send the error but I deleted that all I guess.. how to counter that?

Thanks

Comment: _I want to work better with this and also run a FOR to read each position [x][0] ....._ I'm not sure I understand what you mean, can you expand on that?

Comment: Thats just me saying because I know what I want to do there and I'll post it when I can figure this out. I just want to remove that [""] and the "->" and work better with that output

Comment: Then either delete the elements you don't want, or get the elements you do. It might be worth using regex for at least part of this.

Comment: But the problem is where I do the row.replace and split things...

Comment: It looks like your actual *output* has nested lists which don't conform to your desired *output*. Is that what you are having a problem with?

Comment: @HenriqueMota _But the problem is where I do the row.replace and split things..._ What do you mean, which part of my comment are you responding to?

Comment: @wwii yes. I want it like I said and not what I have.. but I can't work on it

Comment: @AMC I really don't need regex to work on this, actually it can be easy to work with replace and split but I can't, its easy but something is wrong

Comment: _I really don't need regex to work on this, actually it can be easy to work with replace and split_ I didn't say regex was necessary, and I disagree with the second part. The standard string functions can quickly become inadequate. _its easy but something is wrong_ Again, what is wrong?

Comment: You only want to **save** the server url's for lines that start with `'.|'` or for all of them?

Comment: For all ofcouse but I can't get a pattern for all urls because ngrep save it all different, so I want to save the all the next lines I don't care if it come with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix yours replace

```
....
    row = row.replace('U', '').split(' ')
    result.append(row)    # should be result.extend row[1:4]
```

with

```
....
    row = row.replace('U', '').split(' ')
    result.extend(row[1:4])
```

You might consider replacing

```
....
    row = row.replace('.|', '').replace('..', '')
    result.append(row)
```

with

```
....
    row = row.replace('.|', '').replace('..', '')
    result.append(row.strip('.'))
```

---

This is how I would have done it - no regular expressions.

```
import collections,operator
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
interesting = operator.itemgetter(1,2,3)
with open('/etc/openvpn/logs/teste.txt', 'r') as data:
    for line in data:
        if line.startswith('U'):
            line = line.split()
            key = line[-1]
            d[key].extend(interesting(line))
        # account for lines that have something other than
        # a dot in the first two characters by omitting them
        elif line[2:].startswith('.'):
            line = line[2:].replace('..',' ')
            server, *_ = line = line.split()
            # odd number of dots preceding the server address
            if server.startswith('.'):
                server = server[1:]
            d[key].append(server)
        else:
            continue
```

It relies on consistent file format as in your example. It relies on the line that starts with `'U'` to come just before its related line with the server name. It only retrieves the first server address in the *second* line.

The info you want is in the dictionary's values

```
In [29]: for thing in d.values():
    ...:     print(thing)
    ...:     
['2020/03/04', '16:28:01.138292', '10.8.0.4:52014', 'www.google.com']
['2020/03/04', '16:28:03.011371', '10.8.0.4:57054', 'crm.teste.com']
['2020/03/04', '16:28:03.033610', '8.8.8.8:53', 'crm.teste.com']
['2020/03/04', '16:28:05.166480', '10.8.0.4:57284', 'crm.teste.tk']
['2020/03/04', '16:28:05.183755', '8.8.8.8:53', 'crm.teste.tk']
['2020/03/04', '16:28:11.153329', '10.8.0.4:58086', 'cbdfhkrlmnsxtvwz.neverssl.com']
['2020/03/04', '16:28:11.180992', '8.8.8.8:53', 'cbdfhkrlmnsxtvwz.neverssl.com']
['2020/03/04', '16:28:15.851360', '10.8.0.4:60006', 'plus.l.google.com']
['2020/03/04', '16:28:15.859538', '8.8.8.8:53', 'plus.l.google.com']
['2020/03/04', '16:28:17.316359', '10.8.0.4:59708', 'endpoint.prod.eu-west-1.forester.a2z.com']
['2020/03/04', '16:28:17.322547', '8.8.8.8:53', 'endpoint.prod.eu-west-1.forester.a2z.com']
['2020/03/04', '16:28:17.335399', '10.8.0.4:53174', 'aafreudservice.prod.us-east-1.freud.titan.assistant.a2z.com']
['2020/03/04', '16:28:17.341750', '8.8.8.8:53', 'aafreudservice.prod.us-east-1.freud.titan.assistant.a2z.com']
['2020/03/04', '16:28:17.363490', '10.8.0.4:56468', 'match.amazonbrowserapp.de']
['2020/03/04', '16:28:17.369720', '8.8.8.8:53', 'match.amazonbrowserapp.de']
['2020/03/04', '16:28:18.024460', '10.8.0.4:64589', 'identity.browserapps.amazon.de']
['2020/03/04', '16:28:18.030664', '8.8.8.8:53', 'identity.browserapps.amazon.de']
['2020/03/04', '16:28:18.473433', '10.8.0.4:49952', 'titan.service.amazonbrowserapp.co.uk']
['2020/03/04', '16:28:18.479444', '8.8.8.8:53', 'titan.service.amazonbrowserapp.co.uk']


In [30]:
```

---

Using regular expressions.

```
import re
pattern = r'''U\s([^ ]+)\s([^ ]+)\s([^ ]+).*?[.]{2,}(.*?)[.]{2,}'''
log_entry = re.compile(pattern,flags=re.DOTALL)
results = []
with open('/etc/openvpn/logs/teste.txt', 'r') as F:
    data = f.read()
for thing in log_entry.finditer(data):
    results.append(thing.groups())
```

---

Comment: I changed my lines with yours using extend and it seems to work well!
I tried with regular expressions, because its better code but It gives me error, also with the code *This is how I would have done it - no regular expressions.* give me error too! Anyway, thank you!!!

Comment: Hey! I edited my post I got a new error... :( @wwii

Comment: @HenriqueMota - please don't continually mutate your questions in response to answers. Subsequent to asking a question and getting answers if new symptoms appear please just ask a new question - **especially** if you have modified your code from the original.